# Regex: replace comma in between a string Python

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a list of rows like,

Totally 10 columns but the csv generated using [tabula](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabula-py) by 9 columns

ELECSERV FINALED(string values might be change) these two columns generated as one I want to separated by two different columns separated by comma and i then removed comma at the end of row.

```
D12-1234,041-260-32,714 EL DFRO ST,ELECSERV FINALED,0,$0.00,10/15/2009 ,CONSTRUCTION,Electrical service upgrade from 100 amp to 200 amp (same location),
D12-1235,037-071-07,127 S HORN DR,ELECSERV ISSUED,0,$0.00,10/22/2009 ,"AGANS & ELLIOTT, INC, A&E ELECTRIC",Service upgrade (same location),
```

Output should be like this:

```
D12-1234,041-260-32,714 EL DFRO ST,ELECSERV,FINALED,0,$0.00,10/15/2009 ,CONSTRUCTION,Electrical service upgrade from 100 amp to 200 amp (same location)
D12-1235,037-071-07,127 S HORN DR,ELECSERV,ISSUED,0,$0.00,10/22/2009 ,"AGANS & ELLIOTT, INC, A&E ELECTRIC",Service upgrade (same location)
```

Comment: You want to remove the last comma?

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis yes

Comment: I don't understand, why you need regex, when `line.rstrip(",")` gives you your desired output. But then again, this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can first split the line with delimiter as `,`.

```
cols = line.split(',')
```

Now change the 4th element in the result array and replace  by `,`

```
cols[3] = string.replace(cols[3],' ',',')
```

Join the array to form a string and the remove last comma by using `rstrip`

```
','.join(cols).rstrip(',')
```

Edit 1:

Please refer the following line, it's working for me.

```
line = 'D12-1234,041-260-32,714 EL DFRO ST,ELECSERV FINALED,0,$0.00,10/15/2009 ,CONSTRUCTION,Electrical service upgrade from 100 amp to 200 amp (same location),'
cols = line.split(',')
cols[3] = str.replace(cols[3],' ',',')
print(','.join(cols).rstrip(','))
```

Comment: In that line cols[3] = string.replace(cols[3],' ',',') -> string define wt?

Comment: ```string``` is a keyword here. You don't have to define it.

Comment: but it returns an error, NameError: name 'string' is not defined

Comment: Its str not string

Comment: while adding these lines I'm getting error like index out of range

Comment: I have a list which consist of multiple lines, while passing this line        for line in list: print(str.replace(cols[3],' ',','))  getting IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You need to first split each line and then replace the value. Ensure that all the lines has equal number of columns or atleast 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167404/discussion-between-sandesh-gupta-and-dwayne-jhon).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want, also make sure last line has a \n to work properly, you can also add an if statement to check if last char is `\n`.

```
with open("t.csv",'r') as myfile ,open ('out.csv','w') as outputfile:
  for line in myfile:
    outputfile.write(line[:-2]+"\n")
```

Edit : At the end you can write the result to the old file

Comment: already i have converted csv file from tabula and write into another csv file. How could i write this information into existing file which consist of list of lines